# Adding multiple apex-controllers on a manifest.json file of a react app

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, react, lightning-container, manifest

I have a react app that is built and added as a static resource to a lighting component. This react app uses calls to apex (`LCC.callApex`) to get certain necessary data. For the app to be able to connect to the controller, I know it's needed to add the same to the manifest.json file of the React app.

My problem is, I have multiple controllers to which I want to connect and until now I didn't find the solution to how to do so.

These two structures don't work:

```
{
  "short_name": "example short name",
  "name": "example name",
  "icons": [],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "landing-pages": [
    {
      "path": "index.html",
      "apex-controller": [
        "FirstController",
        "SecondController"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And:

```
{
  "short_name": "example short name",
  "name": "example name",
  "icons": [],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "landing-pages": [
    {
      "path": "index.html",
      "apex-controller": "FirstController"
    },
    {
      "path": "index.html",
      "apex-controller": "SecondController"
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what would be the best approach to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Debora, are you able to find the solution/workaround for this issue?